# Best way to crop and upload image with express?

Tags: node.js, express, jcrop

i upload image on S3 server with [knox](https://github.com/LearnBoost/knox) on express.

I would like user could crop the image for this profile picture (like on facebook)

I heard about [Jcrop](https://github.com/tapmodo/Jcrop) for the user interface and [imagemagick](http://imagemagick.org) for the server.
For you, what is the best way to do that ?

*Sorry for my bad english.*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try to use nice library GraphicsMagick for node.js 
https://github.com/aheckmann/gm

and here is a link to test some function and so on 
http://aheckmann.github.com/gm/

```
var gm = require('gm')
  , resizeX = 200
  , resizeY = 400

gm('/path/to/image.jpg')
.resize(resizeX, resizeY)
.write(response, function (err) {
  if (err) ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer is a little late, but I have been working on a module (called Picsee) that does just this, check it out [here](http://dlochrie.github.io/picsee/). It uploads photos, crops photos (you need a client-side library), and saves multiple versions based on your configuration. It uses `GD`, not Image- or GraphicsMagick.

There is also a [demo app](https://github.com/dlochrie/picsee-looksee) that demonstrates how to upload, crop, and save multiple versions of the image. And the example is using `JCrop`. Eventually I hope to add S3 support as well as several other features.